# API calls to openweather map fail on GitHub

Tags: javascript, api, github

I am trying to post one of my projects on my GitHub page. It's a local weather project which displays the weather in your geographical area. The API calls to openweather map are failing. They work both locally and on Codepen but for some reason I get this Error on my GitHub page.

**net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a free appid?  If so, unfortunately, by sharing the link I fear you may have doomed yourself to never being able to accurately troubleshoot this issue.  Per [the appid documentation](http://openweathermap.org/appid) you are only allowed one call every 10 minutes with a free version.  With everybody on StackOverflow clicking the link to check, you'll be exceeding that for sure....

Comment: Yea but then I can just sign up for another API id as long as I can figure out the solution to the original problem

Comment: Right, but my point is that as long as everyone is checking from stackoverflow with a frequency of greater than once every ten minutes, it will almost always be showing some sort of failure or connection error, so it will be difficult to troubleshoot.  I don't know how openweather handles excess calls-- my _hunch_ is just returning an error, but I don't know...

Comment: I see your point, I don't think I saw an x calls per time period restriction like other weather APIs.